# JQuery Show Hide showing multiple content

Tags: jquery, show-hide

Im having trouble making 1 mass showhide for multiple documents.  This showhide must be able to contain other elements within it as well, such as **ol ul li** etc.  Currently I'm having trouble showing the other content besides the  tag as well as adding another showhide inside of the original show hide

Also to display a box with the content in it.

**HTML:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="showhideJQuery.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.showhide {
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    margin:1em .5em;
}
.showhide h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: .25em;
    background:#0033CC;
    border-top:1px solid #666666;
    border-bottom:1px solid #666666;
}
.showhide div {
    padding: .5em .25em;
}
</style>

<body>
<div class="showhide">
    <h3>Title 1</h3>
    <div>
        <ol>
            <li>Hey!</li>
            <div class="showhide">
                <h3>Another one?!</h3>
                <div>YES!</div>
            </div>
        </ol>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div.showhide:eq(0)> div').hide();
$('div.showhide:eq(0)> h3').click(function() { 
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');                                            

});
```

});

Comment: `li`s have to be contained in `ul`s or `ol`s.

Comment: I believe I made a few edits to the post after you commented, sorry.

Comment: Your HTML is still invalid, you have a `<div/>` just floating around inside the `<ol/>` it needs to be inside a list item. plus I think your selector `$('div.showhide:eq(0)> div')` will select ALL `<div/>`s withing the `.showhide` div, including nested show/hides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding class attributes to the item you want to trigger the show/hide and the element you want shown / hidden you can do something like this:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="showhide">
    <h3 class="showhideclick">Title 1</h3>
    <div class="showhidecontainer">
        <ol>
            <li>Hey!</li>
            <div class="showhide">
                <h3 class="showhideclick">Another one?!</h3>
                <div class="showhidecontainer">YES!</div>
            </div>
        </ol>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.showhidecontainer').hide();
    $('.showhideclick').click(function() { 
        $(this).next('.showhidecontainer').slideToggle('fast');                                            
    });
});
```

This also gives you the flexibility to use different elements to contain your hidden content and which element triggers the action.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for all of the help running into this issue though seen here http://jsfiddle.net/TB6vP/7/ when you click on the word "Animation" the tries to come out but doesn't...any thoughts?

Comment: Im assuming it's because I can't put another showhidecontainer inside of another?  I know I have done this with javascript before

Comment: You need to place the <li>How isn't that cool?!</li> inside a <ul></ul> or <ol></ol> for it to work. Also please accept this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TB6vP/1/)**

```
$(function(){
    $('div.showhide > div').hide();
    $('div.showhide > h3').click(function() { 
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');                                        });
});
```

Comment: The demo is working perfectly.  Thank you for the time put in to this, any idea on how to add a background color (box) to the content?

Comment: By content you mean the div which is sliding?

Comment: You can set the background color use `css` method `$("selector").css("backgroundColor", "specifyColorHere")`

Comment: Thank you for all of the help running into this issue though seen here http://jsfiddle.net/TB6vP/7/ when you click on the word "Animation" the tries to come out but doesn't...any thoughts?

Comment: You were missing the enclosing `ol` tag for `li`. I fixed it take a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TB6vP/8/

Comment: Oh fantastic, hopefully lastly...can I not put a showhidecontainter inside of another?  I know I had done this in Javascript...or I guess I should say is there a cleaner way to do this?  This will be the basis of many documents calling in this script and such

Comment: Sorry for another comment but, what would the code look like in JQuery to show another container that was a different background color?
$(this).next('.showhidecontainer').slideToggle('fast');
currently has CSS setup for the background color, what if I wanted to make another called "showhidecontainer2" would it be as simple as adding $(this).next('.showhidecontainer, showhidecontainer2').slideToggle('fast'); ?
Thanks for much again!

Comment: Just `$(this).next()` should be sufficient. It will give the `next` element. Only if you want to make sure the next element matches the required selector then only pass the selector otherwise just `next()` should work in your case

Comment: I just added another jquery line so it looks like this
http://jsfiddle.net/TB6vP/17/
Forsee any issues in the future with this?  Code clean enough to not get jacked up?

Comment: You can keep different classes to control the background. But for sliding animation you can have another common class for all the slide containers and use that in the code. Take a look I have done the necessary changes http://jsfiddle.net/TB6vP/18/

Answer (score 0):

If you get rid of the `:eq(0)` in your jquery selectors, does it do what you want it to?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div.showhide > div').hide();
$('div.showhide > h3').click(function() { 
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');                   
    }); 
});
```